# Finding the K largest elements on Java with O(n+klog n)?

Tags: java

I am suppose to code a method that returns K largest elements with O(n+klogn). code below does the job, but it isn't in the correct time complexity. What could I do to satisfy O(n+klogn)?

Note: Every word has the word it self and the frequency. Such as [Apple 25]. word with the highest frequency is the largest.

```
    public static Word[] heapSelect(Word[] array, int k){
    Word [] words = new Word[k];
    int n = array.length;
    // Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = 0; i< n-1; i++) {
        heapify(array, n, i);
        for (int j = 0; j<n-i-1; j++) 
        { 
            if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1]) < 0){
            swap(array,j, j+1); 
            heapify(array, i, 0); 
        } 
    }
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, words, 0, k);

}
    return words;
}
```

my heapify method.

```
    private static void heapify(Word[] arr, int n, int i) {
    int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root 
    int l = 2*i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1 
    int r = 2*i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2 

    // If left child is larger than root 
    if (l < n && arr[l].compareTo(arr[largest])>0) 
        largest = l; 

    // If right child is larger than largest so far 
    if (r<n && arr[r].compareTo(arr[largest])>0) 
        largest = r; 

    // If largest is not root 
    if (largest != i) 
    { 
        swap(arr,i,largest);

        heapify(arr, n, largest); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: quicksort followed by linear (sufficient) or binary (faster) search

Comment: @WillCain that would give O(n log n) which is larger than the requirement.

Comment: oh, sorry what's klog?

Comment: `k` is the number of elements to find.

Comment: oh *plus* (facepalm), I read O(n klog n), it's O(n + klog n)